# Reading start timecode of Quicktime movie using Python on PC/Linux

Tags: python, video, sdk, video-processing, quicktime

Does anyone know if it's possible to read start timecode from a Quicktime movie using Python and some sort of SDK on PC or Linux?

Really need to do this!

Answer (score 1):

Use [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en). It includes a Python library.